# Imaging simulation slice and adding a shape

Tags: python, data-visualization, physics, astronomy

I have been making slice images of a simulation, now I need to add a shape to the image, the slice has a colour map, I add a circle to the slice, I need help with making the circle colour be adjustable by values, and share the same colormap as the slice.The code I use is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import csv

 def readslice(ndim):
    shape = (ndim,ndim,ndim)
    fd = open("delta_T_v3_no_halos_z013.40_nf0.898994_useTs0_zetaX-1.0e+00_alphaX-1.0_TvirminX-1.0e+00_aveTb027.03_Pop-1_300_200Mpc", 'rb')
    data = np.fromfile(file=fd, dtype= np.dtype('f4')).reshape(shape)
    fd.close()
    print data
    return data
ff =  readslice(300)

circle1=plt.Circle((150.0,150.0),50.0)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)

plt.imshow(ff[0,:,:],cmap = cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()

plt.savefig('picwithcircle.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: some examples would help ... what is slice , show input and at least sketch the desired output otherwise we can only guess what are you dealing with .... discouraging anyone from answer or help